# Site Address and WordPress Address settings when using a load balancer

Tags: redirect, options, wp-config, site-url

I am installing my wordpress forum in two identical servers:

1. InstanceA
   (public dns: instancea.com)
2. InstanceB
   (public dns: instanceb.com)

I would like to have both of these servers sit behind a load balancer:

LB (public dns: lb.com)

When filling in the Site Address and WordPress Address settings in `wp-admin->settings`, which address would I fill for each server?

I would like to use each instance's respective address for these fields. But this causes my load balancer to do a redirect (`301`) to the instance's address (eg: instancea.com).

Thank you.

Comment: The purpose of a load balancer is to evenly spread the load for a single site across multiple servers. By definition, each server should serve a site that looks to the viewer to be on the same public dns name. In practice, for wordpress, this means that both sites should be pointing to the same database and as such can't be configured with different addresses. If you wanted to load balance your database for some reason (the amount of traffic you'd need before the database became the bottleneck would be massive) you can, but load balancing a database, especially for write operations is complex.

Comment: Both sites do point to the same db. I have no interest in load balancing my db.

Comment: Then you can't have different site addresses for each server.  The site address in the wp config should be the dns name of the load balancer.

Comment: Ok. The "WordPress Address" setting ("where my core files reside" - according to the docs) seems like it would be more appropriate to set as the instance's address...However, doing this results in an endless redirect which doesn't allow the page to be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say "where core files reside" they are referring to the url where they can be reached.  Since you're using a load balancer, you want those requests to be split across both your servers.

To configure Wordpress in a load balanced environment, you need to configure a couple of settings.  I like to do this directly in the DB since doing them 1 at a time through the gui will often prevent you from being access the other settings until they are all set.

In the `wp_options` table, set the following to the DNS address of your load balancer.

1. siteurl
2. home

Note, if your wordpress files are located in a sub-directory (e.g. `/wordpress`) then the `siteurl` should be set to the dns name of the load balancer followed by the path to the wordpress directory.

Keep in mind, you will also have to mirror your wp-content directory between your servers somehow. Some people will use some kind of cloud file storage for this (e.g. AWS S3), but there are other ways as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Regarding your last paragraph: I'm just manually uploading the (same) wp-content folder into each respective server. Is this problematic?

Comment: If your site accepts uploads (including media inserted into posts via the wysiwyg) it will be since those will only be uploaded to the `wp-content` folder of the server that was selected to process the upload.  You'll also have to install any plugins you install manually on both servers as well as any theme updates.

Comment: I'm working by making all changes in local environment, then uploading changes to both servers. I will not be making live changes. The editor allows image urls, I don't think it allows media to be uploaded, but I'll look into this issue.

Comment: Any idea why setting the lb address for "home" and "siteurl" would cause a "redirected you too many times" error when visiting the lb url?

Comment: Does your subdomain match your wordpress settings? I.e. are you using `www.website.com` or `website.com` everywhere. It's important not to mix and match

Comment: Sorry, silly capitalization issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do these 2 settings (`siteurl` and `home`) in the dashboard change something in the database? Like I said, I have 2 instances, so I'm wondering if I will need to change these settings on each instance (from the specific instance address to the load balancer address).

Comment: Yes, siteurl and home are the database fields. If both sites use the same database you would only need to change it once.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Regarding the last paragraph of your answer again: do you have any link for me for setting something like that up? Most resources I've found suggest plugins (eg: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) which is problematic because 1) They are themselves plugins so how will I perform their installation and 2) They only consider the wp-content/uploads folder...I am already noticing the need to change more than my code on production (ie: plugins and media).